# Android- Change permissions of app

Tags: android

I know this is not a technical question but I've searched a lot of time and can't find a suitable answer:

I would like to change the permissions of my app. You can find the app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.trigger.forge2dd999d0f14b11e1bc8612313d1adcbe&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImlvLnRyaWdnZXIuZm9yZ2UyZGQ5OTlkMGYxNGIxMWUxYmM4NjEyMzEzZDFhZGNiZSJd

If you look at "Permissions" it says:

YOUR PERSONAL INFORMATION 
READ CONTACT DATA
Allows the app to read all of the contact (address) data stored on your tablet. Malicious apps may use this to send your data to other people. Allows the app to read all of the contact (address) data stored on your phone. Malicious apps may use this to send your data to other people.

And I would like to remove this so that the app does not read contact data of a user. Can someone tell me please how to do that?

Thanks,

enne

Comment: What versions do you have set for `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` in the `<uses-sdk>` element of your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes I've written the app. My minSdkVersion is 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the app doesn't actually access the contacts API, then you can safely remove the corresponding `<uses-permission/>` from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and rebuild your APK.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Comment: You beat me to it, damn, but yes, just drop the permission from your app, and wipe out all references to it in source.

Comment: Depending on the OP's min sdk version, the permissions may be automatically applied rather than being defined in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Jeremy's answer about , looks like the permissions you are using are: `android.permission.READ_PROFILE` and `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`

You need to remove those. For more details check this out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Well I just removed <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> but it still shows the same.

Comment: Ok, it's working now, it seems that it takes some time until permissions get refreshed.